# Экспорт функций классов C++

Tags: c++, компоновщик, name-mangling

Не могу понять как C++ передаёт информацию о функциях, принадлежащих классу, для нашей программы.
К примеру, мы имеем заголовок, в котором в том числе указано:

```
class Object {
public:
   void Func();
}
```

Как он определяет адрес этой функции в DLL, чтобы мы могли её вызывать?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Если кратко, при компиляции компилятор превращает имена функций/функций-членов и т.д. в имена *символов* по специальному алгоритму, говоря цеховым жаргоном, *мэнглит* (*менлит*, *манглит*, *декорирование имён*<sup>¹</sup>, *name decoration*, см. [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)). Этот алгоритм не стандартизован, у каждого компилятора он свой. Так, например, `Object::Func()` становится `?Func@Object@@QEAAXXZ` (msvc) или `_ZN6Object4FuncEv` (gcc). При этом между заменглиным именем и обычным есть взаимооднозначное соответствие: для каждой функции будет уникальное имя, а каждому корректному имени соответствует уникальная функция. Функции языка Си (в отличие от C++) обычно не подвергаются этому процессу или изменяются тривиальным образом (например, добавляется `_` перед именем)<sup>²</sup>. Одна из основных мотиваций применения такого подхода — обеспечить уникальное имя для перегруженных и шаблонных функций.

Так вот, при компиляции и линковке в динамические библиотеки (и исполняемые файлы тоже, в большинстве систем у них одинаковый формат) в бинарный файл записывается специальная секция *таблица символов*. В ней записывается соответствие заменглиного имени и смещение каждой функции внутри библиотеки.

При вызове функции, находящейся в динамической библиотеке, этот вызов превращается компилятором/линкером в нечто подобное:

```
1010:    call <ADDR>
...
ADDR:    jmp GOT[OBJECT_FOO_OFFSET]
```

Где `GOT` (*global offset table* в терминах ELF/linux, *глобальная таблица смещений*) — это специальный объект, в который загружаются адреса всех динамически линкуемых символов, по сути это просто массив адресов всех функций, импортируемых из внешних библиотек. В терминах PE/windows структура с аналогичным назначением называется `IAT`, *import address table*, *таблица адресов импорта*.

`GOT` заполняется при запуске программы: по сути, при загрузке динамически слинкованного исполняемого файла ОС (или специальная программа, динамический линковщик) ищет имена всех импортируемых символов в динамических библиотеках и собственно заполняет эту таблицу, обеспечивая связанность. В результате чего код выше корректно работает.

У этого процесса есть и другие варианты и детали реализации. Некоторые упрощают его, некоторые обеспечивают дополнительную гибкость и безопасность, но общая схема остаётся примерно такой.

---

<sup>¹ Спасибо *@EOF* за указание термина.</sup>
<sup>² Спасибо *@Croessmah* за уточнение.</sup>

Comment: "Функции языка Си (в отличие от C++) не подвергаются этому процессу." в зависимости от соглашения вызова к имени может быть что-то добавлено. Например, нижнее подчеркивание.Это, конечно, не "манглинг" имен, но всё же решил упомянуть.

Comment: _"компилятор превращает имена функций/функций-членов и т.д. в имена символов по специальному алгоритму"_ - это называется "декорирование имён".

Comment: @EOF, ни разу не слышал... откуда такой термин?

Comment: Ну... я его узнал из книг. Но google тоже знает)

Comment: @EOF, опять же, из каких? есть что-то стоящее на что не стыдно сослаться? как я погляжу, термин «name decoration» растёт из документации MS и пока не то чтобы общеупотребим за её пределами...

Comment: Нашел. Это было в книге Стивена Прата - Язык программирования С++. Лекции и упражнения." Страница 403. Незнаю насколько авторитетный источник. Решать Вам.

Comment: **name mangling** - *декорирование имён* (дословно: *искажение имён*)