# Как работает импорт в программах?

Tags: c++, windows, ассемблер, импорт, pe

Разбирался как работает импорт и непонятна одна вещь.Но все по порядку.Когда мы в программе вызываем какую то функцию,имя этой функции является адресом функции.Так...Если написать такой код:

```
  std::cout << Beep << std::endl;
```

Мы получим адрес функции `Beep` из подгруженной библиотеки kernel32.dll.Но откуда берется этот адрес?Как программа знает где загружена эта функция,точнее ее адрес?Я знаю, что адрес можно получить из таблицы импорта,ссылавшись на поле `FirstThunk` структуры `_IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR`,но смотря на дизассемблер,там адрес функции выглядит примерно так: `qword ptr ds:[<&Beep>]`  .Читаю про регистр ds,он должен ссылаться на секцию данных.Смотрю на регистр,он у меня: DS 002B. C этого момента я в тупике.Ведь,что это за смещение такое "002B", оно ведь слишком маленькое,откуда его отсчитывать..Мне крайне непонятен механизм импорта и связывания функций.

Comment: «*смотря на дизассемблер, там адрес функции выглядит примерно так: qword ptr ds:[<&Beep>]*» — можешь точно строчку процитировать?

Comment: @ Fat-Zer, `call qword ptr ds:[<&Beep>]` вызов функции

Comment: определённости ради, это ассемблированная строка, полученная от компилятора, а не дезасемблированная строка из бинарника, ведь так?

Comment: ладно... не важно... ответ всё равно писать не буду т.к. детали реализации win всё равно не знаю... про общую схему уже недавно писал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1179517/%d0%ad%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-c/1179528#1179528 …

Comment: Про DS: в строчке выше он ничего не значит, его можно просто опустить… а вообще в [защищённом режиме](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC) x86+ в нём хранится не смещение, а адрес селектора в [GDT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDT)… AFAIK ни одна современные ОС не использует возможности сегментации i386, так что он указывает просто на всё виртуальное адресное пространство процесса.

Comment: @Fat-Zer я же написал,дизассемблированная

Comment: @Fat-Zer , виртуальное адресное пространство процесса далеко не с того адреса начинается

Comment: просто не похоже... в дизассемблированном листинге вместо символа `Beep` уже должен был бы стоять конкретный адрес со смещением... возможно относительно `rip`... а то что это `Beep` могло идти в комментариях... но опять же, могу заблуждаться — дизассемблер может быть и слишком умным...

Comment: в смысле? Виртуальное АП начинается с `0`...

Comment: А ничего что там лежит стек, куча, системные компоненты? Даже если так, посему ds не равно всегда 0?

Comment: и да, оговорился, в DS не адрес, а индекс селектора в GDT, конечно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а gdt случайно не присущ только x86 архитектуре?

Comment: если кратко, то значение в DS — просто особенность реализации ОС... ничего осмысленного изнутри ОС в нём нет и повлиять на него обычно нельзя... и да, конечно, это всё относится только к пост-x86 архитектурам (пост i286, если точнее)...

Comment: Так где тут `import`? Уточните заголовок

Comment: Имя функции не является адресом функции.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Если написать такой код ... Мы получим адрес функции Beep из подгруженной библиотеки kernel32.dll

То, что выведет код `std::cout << Beep`, далеко не обязательно реальный адрес функции, причины описаны здесь: [Что такое адрес функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1107372/240512)

> Читаю про регистр ds,он должен ссылаться на секцию данных

Скорее всего, это просто ошибка дизассемблера, с чего бы адресу функции быть в секции данных? У меня вызов функции Beep превращается вот в такое в выводе `dumpbin /disasm`:

```
FF 15 00 B0 41 00  call dword ptr [__imp__Beep@8]
```

Код инструкции FF 15 (с учетом opcode extensions) здесь обозначает "Call near, absolute indirect, address given in r/m32" - т.е. вызов функции по адресу в заданной ячейке памяти (см. https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html). Операнд 00 B0 41 00 - сам адрес (перевернутый). Человеко-читаемый адрес тут будет: 0x41B000. Смотрим в выводе dumpbin секции:

```
SECTION HEADER #5
  .idata name
     CDF virtual size
   1B000 virtual address (0041B000 to 0041BCDE)
```

То есть адрес функции ожидаемо попадает в секцию .idata, таблицу импорта. Из вывода `dumpbin /imports` узнать более точно:

```
KERNEL32.dll
    41B000 Import Address Table
    41B268 Import Name Table
```

Как видно, 41B000 - это начало Import Address Table модуля KERNEL32.dll. Эта таблица заполняется загрузчиком ОС при запуске программы, куда он пишет уже реальные адреса функций в загруженных модулях.

Comment: а можно пару уточняющих вопросов про детали: я так понимаю, IAT будет отдельная для каждой библиотеки? в неё загружаются только адреса используемых символов (или все, что есть в библиотеке)? адрес IAT задаётся на этапе сборки exe'шника? PIE/[ASLR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR) не используется по умолчанию? Как будет выглядеть вызов в таком случае? есть ли разница между ABI на x86 и amd64? будет ли чем-то отличаться вызов функции одной библиотеки изнутри другой?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Отдельная для каждой библиотеки, загружаются только используемые функции. Адрес задается на этапе сборки, но может быть изменен при использовании ASLR, в этом случае загрузчик будет проходить по всей секции кода и пересчитывать адреса. ASLR используется, если модуль собран с флагом "Dynamic base" - включен по умолчанию в новых версиях Visual C++. Вызов, получается, выглядит также, отличаются действия загрузчика.

Comment: ABI отличается. На x86 зоопарк соглашений о вызовах, на 64 - одно стандартное. Вызов функции одной библиотеки изнутри другой - почти не отличается, с тем исключением, что библиотека всегда должна "быть готовой" к загрузке по произвольному адресу, даже без ASLR. Ведь по фиксированному адресу место может быть занято другой DLL.

Comment: я правильно понял, что ради ASLR загрузчик перелопачивает весь код и меняет адреса прямо в опкодах o_O!? про ABI (как впрочем и всё остальное) я это всё спрашивал компаративистски ради: в elf на GNU/Linux используется одна таблица на весь бинарник (GOT, Global Offset Table) и на x86 под её адрес отводится `ebx`, а на amd64 — она адресуется по относительному смещению от `rip` (весёлая у линкера жизнь)... думал в PEEXE будет нечто подобное...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Да, это так, все абсолютные адреса-операнды загрузчик меняет прямо в секции кода. Секция .reloc содержит таблицу блоков, которые должны быть изменены. А в понятие ABI в Windows входит фактически только соглашение о вызове (как передавать параметры/очищать стек) и способ декорирования имени. На способ хранения адреса функции он не влияет.

Comment: нуда... неверно выразился... это не то чтобы ABI... это просто особенность реализации...

Comment: Заметил одну деталь,вы пишете, опкод FF15 это "вызов функции по адресу в заданной ячейке памяти".Но у меня после опкода не абсолютный адрес,а относительный(относительно следующей инструкции).Вопрос очень важный,прошу ответить на него

Comment: @Whitehorse Да, действительно, в 64-битном режиме значение этого опкода переопределено, и операнд интерпретируется как относительный, а не абсолютный адрес. Все остальное это не меняет, адрес так же указывает на таблицу импорта.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight и еще,адреса ведь ме могут быть постоянными, потому что база загрузки приложения постоянно разная, без разницы x64 или x32

Comment: @Whitehorse Читайте выше обсуждение с Fat-Zer. Еще как могут. А в х64 абсолютные адреса просто реже используются, из-за того, что они в 2 раза больше, а также, когда создавались 64-битные ОС, уже появилось понимание в необходимости ASLR и соответственно проектировалось все уже с учетом этого.